# How to set the upstream servers of dnsmasq on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I want to set the upstream servers of `dnsmasq` on ubuntu 15.10. I've read a lot of documentations or resources about dnsmasq, in which they referred to a configuration file called `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but I couldn't find it. I tried to find out how `dnsmasq` was started when system booted, but I couldn't find `dnsmasq` under `/etc/init.d`, either.

So which file should I modify to set the upstream servers of `dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

If your system runs a dhcp client then edit the dhclient.conf, you have to uncomment/modify the `prepend domain-name-server` section as:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```

Create a file `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf` that contains:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver <your ISP DNS>
```

copy the file `/usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example` in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf` and modify it to your needs. You have to add the line:

> resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf

Then use networkmanager to launch dnsmasq. Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` inserting in the [main] section  `dns=dnsmasq`

try dig:

```
dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u2-Debian <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45033
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.147
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.144
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.145
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.146
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.148

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 17 01:43:19 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

Then restart networking and NetworkManager and retry dig:

```
systemctl restart networking
systemctl restart NetworkManager
dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u2-Debian <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34735
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.144
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.147
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.145
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.148
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.232.146

;; Query time: 30 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 17 01:46:38 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

As you can see the *resolver* now is 127.0.0.1. If you dig again you will see that the query time will slow down to 0. This indicate that dnsmasq is running.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot. But could you elaborate any further about how to set upstream servers? I tried to set `server=8.8.8.8` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but it didn't work. Dnsmasq still uses `127.0.1.1` as the upstream server.